# how to add context menu in webview

Tags: java, webview, contextmenu, javafx-2, javafx

I want to add a context menu on webview or fxpanel . while right clicking on a webview instead of copy and reload another context menu should be added.

```
  by default it shows reload or copy after text selection .
```

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues in Jira right now on this. You cannot add to the default menu, or replace it. Might be fixed in Java 8.